# Chrome Printing disabled

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

When I went to go print from Chrome (Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)) this morning, all the print options were disabled and I could not change the printer.
[image]

On IE it works, and I see 12 Printers in my devices and Printers screen.  I am running Windows 10.

**UPDATE**
The plugin is enabled.  Also clicking the button to the right, even though I don't want to use PDF, spins and does not return.  I waited 3 minutes.  What is worrisome is that the left side is all grayed out and Chrome is stating 0 pages to be printed.  This can not be correct.

Note: Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> brings up the system Print Dialog with all the printers and the correct default one set.

[image]

Comment: The answer is in the question. Please read the text in the grey box on the right.

Comment: I tried that.  .

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome and type `chrome://plugins/` [image: Sample]

If this option is disabled, Enable it then you can use your printer.

Comment: It is already enabled ... see updated pic

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste to link bar

> chrome://plugins/

Search Chrome PDF Viewer and enable it

Comment: Same as previous answer

Comment: It is already enabled ... see updated pic